# Object DOMDocument should be created

Tags: magento2, php

I recently converted a Magento 1.9 module to be compatible with Magento 2. all was going well until I got this error:

> Object DOMDocument should be created

I'm not experienced enough in Magento and PHP to figure out how to fix this so I linked the converted module below.

[magento 1.9 module in question](https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_SocialConnect)

I put the converted module [here on github](https://github.com/CallumBrankin/Magento2-Inchoo-Social-Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var/generation`,`var/di`  and then **recompile** using below command.

```
sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and then check maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Recently during a module development I got the same kind of error. In my case I found out the real error which was:

> Circular dependency: Vendor\Module\Helper\Data depends on Vendor\Module\Helper\Bot and vice versa.

I removed this dependency from the `__construct` method of my helpers (refactored them using one parent class) and error is gone. So I'll recommend you to check circular dependencies in your code.